# AlamofireImage: How to downdload images with POST request

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, urlrequest, alamofireimage

AlamofireImage seems to be supposed to request with GET method in general. But in our project, to download images we have to request with POST method, because we send access token. I have searched for the similar question in Stack Overflow, but I couldn't find enough answers. Does anyone know how to download with POST request?

The URL is as follow:

`https://host_name/project_name/GetImage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `af_setImage` method from `AlamofireImage` extension of `UIImageView` and pass any `URLRequestConvertible` parameter. For example, create `URLRequest` instance with Alamofire initializer:

```
let urlPath = "https://host_name/project_name/GetImage"
if var imageRequest = try? URLRequest(url: urlPath, method: .post) {
    imageRequest.addValue("token", forHTTPHeaderField: "token_field")
    imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: imageRequest)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this.

Answer (score 1):

Because We have to send parameters in HTTPBodyData, following the Loe's answer, I made some changes to our code. The following is our new code:

```
let urlPath = "https://host_name/project_name/GetImage"
let parameters:[String: Any] = [
        "token": "tokenValue",
        "imageName": "imageName"
    ]
let dataRequest = Alamofire.request(urlPath,
                                    method: HTTPMethod.post,
                                    parameters: parameters,
                                    encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                                    headers: [:])
guard let imageRequest = dataRequest.request else {
    return
}
imageView.af_setImage(withURLRequest: imageRequest)
```

The Point is first, we create a `DataRequest`object and then convert it to `URLRequest` Type with `Alamofire.request()`method.